# Python 2 compiler doesn't read the correct values after the 31st inputted value

Tags: python

Solving the Smoothing the Weather problem on Codeabbey. It prints the correct output for the first 32 values after which it doesn't read the inputted values correctly. Inputted test values are well over 150.
Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division

num=int(raw_input());

inp=((raw_input()).split(" "));
lists=[];
for i in inp:
    if inp.index(i)==0 or inp.index(i)==len(inp)-1:
        lists.append(inp[inp.index(i)])

    else:
        a,b,c=0.0,0.0,0.0;
        a=float(inp[(inp.index(i))+1])
        b=float(inp[inp.index(i)])
        c=float(inp[(inp.index(i))-1])


        x=(a+b+c)/3

        x = ("%.9f" % x).rstrip('0')

        lists.append(x)



for i in lists:
    print i,
```

Comment: Its not relevant though but dont use semicolons in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The *index* in the following code will always return the first occurrence of i in inp. So, if there are duplicate values in inp, then the whole logic fails.

```
if inp.index(i)==0 or inp.index(i)==len(inp)-1:
    lists.append(inp[inp.index(i)])
```

The correct approach would be to enumerate and us correct indices:

```
from __future__ import division

num = int(raw_input())

inp = ((raw_input()).split(" "))
lists = []
for i, item in enumerate(inp):   # This will loop through inp, while filling the next item in item and keep on incrementing i each time starting with 0
    if i == 0 or i == len(inp)-1:
        lists.append(inp[i])
    else:
        a = float(inp[i+1])
        b = float(inp[i])
        c = float(inp[i-1])

        x = (a+b+c) / 3.0
        x = ("%.9f" % x).rstrip('0')
        lists.append(x)

for i in lists:
    print i,
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just realized my blunder! Thank you for the help. Would it be possible to get in touch with your via mail?

Comment: Thanks @sumeetmufc, I am glad you liked it. For code, I just tried with 100 inputs and it (my code) worked perfectly fine. Could you please post the exact input list which is failing?

Comment: Sure you can contact me at neha.nehavikas.vikas@gmail.com, You didnt check my site properly, it was there on my site as well :)